# Random icons .pac-icon Google Address Autocomplete

Tags: css, google-maps

On desktop the `.pac-icon` for Google Address Autcomplete looks fine.
[image: google address autocomplete]

But when I switch to a mobile resolution there are a lot of random icons displayed.

I can't figure out why this happens. This is my css to customize the Google Address Autocomplete-dropdown.

```
.pac-container {
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.pac-container:after{
    content:none !important;
}
.pac-item,
.pac-item-query {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
.pac-item-query {
    color: #2D728F;
}
.pac-item {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.pac-icon {
    background-image: url("/assets/media/images/icons/location.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
.pac-item:hover > .pac-icon {
    background-image: url("/assets/media/images/icons/location-orange.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Added `! important` after the `background-image`s. Seems like Google overwrites the custom background-image on mobile.